# Make Javascript do List Comprehension

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, list-comprehension, language-comparisons

What is the cleanest way to make Javascript do something *like* Python's list comprehension?

In Python if I have a list of objects whose name's I want to 'pull out' I would do this...

```
list_of_names = [x.name for x in list_of_objects]
```

In javascript I don't really see a more 'beautiful' way of doing that other than just using a for loop construct.

FYI: I'm using jQuery; maybe it has some nifty feature that makes this possible?

More specifically, say I use a jQuery selector like `$('input')` to get all `input` elements, how would I *most cleanly* create an array of all the `name` attributes for each of these `input` elements--i.e., all of the `$('input').attr('name')` strings in an array?

Comment: You can do better than that Python ;-) Well, it's sorta hackish because the language syntax isn't all there but ... see Functional JavaScript -- http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/ (actually, there is extra magic with Python generators but...)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

generic case using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), requires javascript 1.6 (that means, works on every browser but IE < 9) *or* with an object augmenting framework like MooTools works on every browser:

```
var list_of_names = document.getElementsByTagName('input').map(
  function(element) { return element.getAttribute('name'); }
);
```

If dealing with an iterable that doesn't provide `map` (such as [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to first create an array:

```
[...Array(10).keys()].map(x => x * 2 + 3)
```

Spread syntax will also work with arrays, so if you need to apply `map` to any iterable, it's safest to first spread it into a list.

(Note this example also uses an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which requires ES6 support. Most browser versions support both or neither. IE supports neither, if it itself needs to be supported, though IE has been replaced by Edge for awhile.)

jQuery specific example, works on every browser:

```
var list_of_names = jQuery.map(jQuery('input'), function(element) { return jQuery(element).attr('name'); });
```

the other answers using `.each` are wrong; not the code itself, but the implementations are sub-optimal.

**Edit:** there's also [Array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_comprehensions) introduced in Javascript 1.7, but this is purely dependant on syntax and cannot be emulated on browsers that lack it natively. This is the closest thing you can get in Javascript to the Python snippet you posted. However that [got removed from the language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Array_comprehensions)

Comment: note that I directly used `jQuery()` instead of `$()` as I didn't put the snippet inside a closure :) feel free to replace it with $ if you are running inside `(function($){ })(jQuery)`

Comment: I don't understand your implementation using the `map` function...? it takes an array and then a function... how is `jQuery('input')` an array?

Comment: The jQuery object is an array-like object, so it works as the first parameter on all the functions included in the Utilities module that accept an array-like object as a parameter. If you did `jQuery('input').map(...)` instead, then you would have ended with an array-like object (the jQuery object wrapping an array) in `list_of_names` instead of a vanilla javascript Array.

Comment: nice one, best answer i see here then :) +1

Comment: thanks :), remember you can mostly always reduce the jQuery case to simply `var list_of_names = $.map($('input'), function(element) { return $(element).attr('name'); });`

Comment: Great! The jQuery map function is definitely what I was looking for. I noticed it in the jQuery docs, but it never clicked with me what it was there for. Still not as pretty as Python list comprehension but $.map($('input'), function(e) { return $(e).attr('name') }) is probably about as clean as you can get.

Comment: The original/top example does not work with `getElementsByTagName` returning a `HTMLCollection` which has no `map` attribute. Can someone with rep. to edit please integrate the spread syntax (second version) with that example.

Answer (score 12):

A list comprehension has a few parts to it.

1. Selecting a set of something
2. From a set of Something
3. Filtered by Something

In JavaScript, as of ES5 (so I think that's supported in IE9+, Chrome and FF) you can use the `map` and `filter` functions on an array.

You can do this with map and filter:

```js
var list = [1,2,3,4,5].filter(function(x){ return x < 4; })
               .map(function(x) { return 'foo ' + x; });

console.log(list); //["foo 1", "foo 2", "foo 3"]
```

That's about as good as it's going to get without setting up additional methods or using another framework.

**As for the specific question...**

**With jQuery:**

```
$('input').map(function(i, x) { return x.name; });
```

**Without jQuery:**

```
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), 0),
    names = inputs.map(function(x) { return x.name; });
```

`[].slice.call()` is just to convert the `NodeList` to an `Array`.

Comment: This has become much more readable now with ES6 arrow functions:

`var list = [1,2,3,4,5].filter(x => x < 4).map(x => 'foo ' + x);`

Answer (score 6):

Those interested in "beautiful" Javascript should probably check out [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), a language which compiles to Javascript. It essentially exists because Javascript is missing things like list comprehension.

In particular, Coffeescript's list comprehension is even more flexible than Python's. See the [list comprehension docs here](http://coffeescript.org/#loops).

For instance this code would result in an array of `name` attributes of `input` elements.

```
[$(inp).attr('name') for inp in $('input')]
```

A potential downside however is the resulting Javascript is verbose (and IMHO confusing):

```
var inp;
[
  (function() {
    var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
    _ref = $('input');
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      inp = _ref[_i];
      _results.push($(inp).attr('name'));
    }
    return _results;
  })()
];
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that this works because jQuery objects act "like arrays" which is what Coffeescript is expecting in its for loops.

Comment: Is it really "beautiful" Javascript if it outputs what we see above?

Comment: @XMLilley, I agree--I'm very torn about Coffeescript. That's why I included the JS ouput, to make it clear that Coffeescript isnt all sunshine and rainbows.

Comment: @XMLilley This is why we have [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Answer (score 4):

So, python's list comprehensions actually do two things at once: mapping and filtering. For example:

```
list_of_names = [x.name for x in list_of_object if x.enabled]
```

If you just want the mapping part, as your example shows, you can use jQuery's map feature. If you also need filtering you can use jQuery's "grep" feature.

Comment: Actually `$.map()` can be used for filtering too! If you `return null` inside the mapping function jQuery removes that element from the array.

Answer (score 3):

#### Do this in 2020

```
const names = collection.map(x => x.name);
```

[MDN | Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

#### Old Answer from 2012

Yeah—I miss list comprehensions too.

Here's an answer that's slightly less verbose than @gonchuki's answer and converts it into an actual array, instead of an object type.

```
var list_of_names = $('input').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('name');
}).toArray();
```

A use case of this is taking all checked checkboxes and joining them into the hash of the URL, like so:

```
window.location.hash = $('input:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
}).toArray().join(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

A re-usable way of doing this is to create a tiny jQuery plugin like this:

```
jQuery.fn.getArrayOfNames = function() {
    var arr = [];
    this.each( function() { arr.push(this.name || ''); } );
    return arr;
};
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
var list_of_names = $('input').getArrayOfNames();
```

It's not list comprehension, but that doesn't exist in javascript. All you can do is use javascript and jquery for what it's good for.

Comment: It's being defined as a plugin -- i.e. it's a custom method that runs on the jQuery object.

Comment: yeah... sorry about that, i re read the answer and understood it, felt like an idiot and deleted my comment :P

Answer (score 2):

**Added by @yurik: Do not use. Array comprehensions were proposed but [later removed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Array_comprehensions).**

Array comprehensions are a part of the ECMAScript 6 draft. Currently (January 2014) only Mozilla/Firefox's JavaScript implements them.

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
var squares = [i*i for (i of numbers)]; // => [1,4,9,16]
var somesquares = [i*i for (i of numbers) if (i > 2)]; // => [9,16]
```

Though ECMAScript 6 recently switched to left-to-right syntax, similar to C# and F#:

```
var squares = [for (i of numbers) i*i]; // => [1,4,9,16]
```

http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Array_comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

There is a one line approach, it involves using a nested closure function in the
constructor of the list. And a function that goes a long with it to generate the sequence.
Its defined below:

```
var __ = generate = function(initial, max, list, comparision) {
  if (comparision(initial))
    list.push(initial);
  return (initial += 1) == max + 1 ? list : __(initial, max, list, comparision);
};

[(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 30, [], function(x) { return x > 10; }))];
// returns Array[20]
var val = 16;
[(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 30, [], function(x) { return x % val == 4; }))];
// returns Array[2]
```

This is a range based implementation like Python's range(min, max)
In addition the list comprehension follows this form:

```
[{closure function}({generator function})];
```

some tests:

```
var alist = [(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 30, [], function(x) { return x > 10; }))];
var alist2 = [(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 1000, [], function(x) { return x > 10; }))];
// returns Array[990]
var alist3 = [(function(l){ return l; })(__(40, 1000, [], function(x) { return x > 10; }))];
var threshold = 30*2;
var alist3 = [(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 65, [], function(x) { return x > threshold; }))];
// returns Array[5]
```

While this solution is not the cleanest it gets the job done. And in production i'd probably advise against it.

Lastly one can choose not to use recursion for my "generate" method as it would do the job quicker. Or even better use a built in function from of the many popular Javascript libraries. Here is an overloaded implementation that would also accommodate for object properties

```
// A list generator overload implementation for
// objects and ranges based on the arity of the function.
// For example [(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 30, [], function(x) { return x > 10; }))] 
// will use the first implementation, while
// [(function(l){ return l; })(__(objects, 'name', [], function(x, y) { var x = x || {}; return x[y] }))];
// will use the second.

var __ = generator = function(options) {
  return arguments.length == 4 ?
// A range based implemention, modeled after pythons range(0, 100)
  (function (initial, max, list, comparision) {
    var initial = arguments[0], max = arguments[1], list = arguments[2], comparision = arguments[3];
    if (comparision(initial))
      list.push(initial);
    return (initial += 1) == max + 1 ? list : __(initial, max, list, comparision);
  })(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3]):
// An object based based implementation. 
  (function (object, key, list, check, acc) {
    var object = arguments[0], key = arguments[1], list = arguments[2], check = arguments[3], acc = arguments[4];
    acc = acc || 0;
    if (check(object[acc], key))
      list.push(object[acc][key]);
    return (acc += 1) == list.length + 1 ? list : __(object, key, list, check, acc); 
  })(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4]);
};
```

Usage:

```
var threshold = 10;
[(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 65, [], function(x) { return x > threshold; }))];
// returns Array[5] -> 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
var objects = [{'name': 'joe'}, {'name': 'jack'}];
[(function(l){ return l; })(__(objects, 'name', [], function(x, y) { var x = x || {}; return x[y] }))];
// returns Array[1] -> ['Joe', 'Jack']
[(function(l){ return l; })(__(0, 300, [], function(x) { return x > 10; }))];
```

The syntax sucks I know!

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a place where [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) really shines

```
pows = [x**2 for x in foo_arr]
list_of_names = [x.name for x in list_of_objects]
```

The equivalent Javascript would be:

```js
var list_of_names, pows, x;

pows = [
  (function() {
    var _i, _len, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = foo_arr.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      x = foo_arr[_i];
      _results.push(Math.pow(x, 2));
    }
    return _results;
  })()
];

list_of_names = [
  (function() {
    var _i, _len, _results;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = list_of_objects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      x = list_of_objects[_i];
      _results.push(x.name);
    }
    return _results;
  })()
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `.each()` function, you can loop through each element, get the index of the current element and using that index, you can add the name attribute to the `list_of_names` array...

```
var list_of_names = new Array();

$('input').each(function(index){
  list_of_names[index] = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

While this is essentially a looping method, which you specified you did not want, it is an incredibly neat implementation of looping and allows you to run the loop on specific selectors.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[Array comprehensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20210708041948/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Array_comprehensions), which are very similar to Python's list comprehensions, were proposed for ECMAScript 6 but dropped in favor of [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). One advantage of the `Array` methods is they can be implemented if not supported natively; libraries such as core.js do this.

Note the following examples use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which require ES6 support and can't be polyfilled. This shouldn't be an issue, as most browsers that support one of the features used should support all (some browsers added the features at different versions, but there wasn't a large gap). IE is the exception, supporting only `Array.map` (and that only beginning with IE 9). Hopefully, IE won't need to be supported, as it's been replaced by Edge for some time now.

### Array.map

`Array.map` takes a function that will transform each element. Basically, the function corresponds to the expression in a Python list comprehension.

```
var list_of_names = list_of_objects.map(obj => obj.name);
```

#### Non-Arrays

If dealing with a collection or iterable that doesn't provide `map` (such as a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) or a [`NodeList`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist)), it can be converted to an array using one of a couple different features, such as [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

##### Spread Syntax

Spread syntax, which is only supported in specific contexts, works by expanding the elements from an iterable into that context:

```
[...Array(10).keys()].map(x => x+3)
```

Spread syntax will also work with arrays (since they're iterables), though it's not necessary to do so:

```
var ints = [1,2,3,4];
[...ints].map(x => x*2)
```

If you need to apply `map` to an iterable that may or may not be an array, it's safest to first spread it into a list.

##### Array.from

The `Array.from` method converts not only iterables but anything array-like (i.e. has a `length` property and integer indices) to an array:

```
var list_of_names = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[name]'))
        .map(elt => elt.name);
```

As with spread syntax, `Array.from` is safe to apply to arrays. If you need to apply `map` to non-iterable array-like objects as well as arrays and iterables, it's the safest, most general approach.

### Array.filter

`if` clauses in a Python list comprehension translate to [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
// odd natural numbers < 10
[...Array(10).keys()].filter(x => x%2)
```

If the Python example were expanded to include an `if` clause as:

```
list_of_names = [x.name for x in list_of_objects if '-' not in x.value]
```

This would translate to:

```
var list_of_names = Array.from(list_of_objects)
  .filter(obj => ! obj.value.contains('-'))
  .map(obj => obj.name)
```

### JQuery

JQuery provides [`.map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`jQuery.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), both of which incorporate the functionality of [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and `Array.filter`. Depending on the jQuery version, `jQuery.map` can be applied to arrays and array-like objects<sup>*</sup>, though not generators (according to my testing). Note `.map` differs from `jQuery.map` in that it passes arguments in the opposite order (`index, item` rather than `item, index`) and returns a jQuery object.

```
$('input').map((i, a) => a.name);
$.map(Array(10), (_, i) => i);
$.map(document.forms, elt => elt.id);
```

<sup>*</sup>The jQuery documentation asserts that array-like objects should first be converted to an array with (e.g.) [`jQuery.makeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/). Applying `jQuery.map` directly to array-like objects worked when I tested it, though there may be some cases where this causes issues.