# What are some popular JavaScript shortcuts/tricks?

Tags: javascript, shortcut

I've used JavaScript for a while and thought it would be useful (especially for those new to the language) to list some of my favorite shortcuts.

**Ternary operator**

Replace: `if(a) then {b} else {c}`
With: `(a) ? b:c;`

**Unary plus operator**

Replace `parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(y,10)` with `+x + +y`

**Array creation**

Replace `var ary = new Array();` with `var ary = [];`

**Declaring variables**

Replace `var x; var y; var z = 3;` with `var x, y, z=3;`

**Multiline string (almost here-doc style)**

Replace:

```
var str = 'this';
var str += 'covers';
var str += 'multiple';
var str += 'lines';
```

with:

```
var str = 'this \
covers \
multiple \
lines";
```

What others do you use?

Comment: `var str += 'covers';` is invalid. The number conversion methods are definitely not equal, see [Comparison between all number-conversion methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8112802/938089?are-there-are-any-side-effects-of-using-this-method-to-convert-a-string-to-an-in).

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I think that the OP means "Allow to write strings on multiple lines", since the suggested method does not include newlines either.

Comment: Oops, quite right. I'll remove my other comment.

Comment: See the readme at https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/ for some tricks.

Answer (score 5):

To shorten the if condition blocks.

From:

```
var x;

if (a) {
    x = a;
} else if (b) {
    x = b;
} else {
    x = 100;
}
```

to:

```
x = a || b || 100;
```

You can use && to do the similar logic as well.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to string by adding empty string.  Example:

```
var n = 1;
var s = 1 + '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a question.

But you can use:

```
var a = {};
```

in place of:

```
var a = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of them will be object creation:

var obj = {};   instead of   var obj = new Object();

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension. Especially useful if you create a range method:

```
function range(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    yield i;
}

[2 * x for (x in range(100)) if (x * x > 3)]
```

in place of:

```
var myArray = []

for (x in range(100)){

    if (x * x > 3)
    {
        myArray.push(2*x);
    }

}
```

(Example taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28list_comprehension%29#JavaScript))

Comment: is `[2 * x for (x in range(100)) if (x * x > 3)]` a valid javascript syntax?

Comment: I believe its from 1.7 onwards, it should create an array ^_^

Comment: based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions, i tried to run it in FF9 (>3), and it pops a JS error.

Comment: Theres an answer to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964456/make-javascript-do-list-comprehension